# How do I export textures in Blender that are not in UV image editor?

Tags: texturing

So I made a tree and tried to export the material as a PNG, but it is not In the UV Image editor? The textures are from Blenders color mixer thing, they are not something I imported.

Comment: By colour mixer thing do you mean a proceedural texture created with nodes, or vertex colours, or what?

Comment: provide some image what your looking for